# Places name and coordinates using maps in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using this library https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_webservice
and I have this variable:

```
final places = new GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: "<api key>");
```

How I could get the user to get a suggestion of places when he types in a textField. For Example he types "Google hq" and he gets suggested for example *Googleplex, Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, California, Stati Uniti*?

I tried to find a way to get all the suggested places names and coordinates but failed. Is it possible?

I've also tried with the example on the page, but when I execute this:

```
PlacesSearchResponse response = await places.searchByText("google HQ");

   print(response.results.length);
```

I get 0 as result, so it means that there is no available place.

Comment: Have you tried adding PlacesSearchResponse reponse = await places.searchByText("Google HQ"); and then looking at the response object ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgoy to add it in the question. I'm adding it.

Comment: Is it still 0 length with a post code or similar ?

Comment: what do you mean with "a post code"?

Comment: A zip code or whatever it is called to describe a small location near you. Or just "Mountain View, California" for example. Just something other than google hq.

Comment: I get no result still. even by putting the entire name of the place